# how to make countdown timer rotate for each second?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, countdowntimer

I want to change this jsfiddle [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/Raghava0330/gs3WY/243/). It uses jQueryCountDown (http://plugins.jquery.com/countdown360/)

It currently rotates an outer ring, by one increment every second, but this shows as an anti-clockwise rotation of the ring as it counts downs.

I want the countdown to still rotate each second, but the direction of the outer ring rotation should be clockwise (currently the ring rotates anti-clockwise). Please see the example:

Example code:

```
var countdown = $("#countdown").countdown360({
    radius: 60,
    seconds: 20,
    label: ['sec', 'secs'],
    fontColor: '#FFFFFF',
    autostart: false,
    onComplete: function () {
      console.log('done');
    }
});

countdown.start();

$('#countdown').click(function() {
  countdown.extendTimer(2);
});
```

Comment: what do you mean with `should be rotate` ? What exactly should be rotating ?

Comment: That plugin is hard-coded to rotate anti-clockwise. Do you want to modify the plugin?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie is right. You'll need to modify the plugin for that. **[Here](https://github.com/johnschult/jquery.countdown360/blob/master/src/jquery.countdown360.js)**'s the source. The `_drawCountDownShape` method controls how the widget is rendered. If you're not familiar with rendering, I'd recommend against getting into this.

Comment: @kumar jerry: You will obviously need to minify the modified plugin script, but there are plenty of tools around to do that.  Do you have any feedback on my answer?

Answer (score 3):

That plugin is hard-coded to rotate anti-clockwise. I updated the original plugin so that it now has an option to have `clockwise: true`.

The new demo looks like this:

[image]

This example has one running clockwise and the second running normally (anti-clockwise):

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/gs3WY/246/

In the `defaults` I added `clockwise`:

```
    defaults = {
        ...[snip]...
        clockwise: false
    };
```

In the `start` method I made it conditionally draw the "stroke" (the outer ring):

```
    start: function () {
        ...[snip]...
        this._drawCountdownShape(Math.PI * 3.5, !this.settings.clockwise);
        ...[snip]...
    },
```

and in the `_draw` method I added a conditional calculation of the angle. Also when the timer ends, it conditionally draws the outer ring again based on the clockwise flag (previously it always redrew the entire outer ring before rendering the changes):

```
    _draw: function () {
        var secondsElapsed = Math.round((new Date().getTime() - this.startedAt.getTime()) / 1000);
        if (this.settings.clockwise) {
            var endAngle = (((Math.PI * 2) / this.settings.seconds) * secondsElapsed) - (Math.PI * .5);
        } else {
            var endAngle = (Math.PI * 3.5) - (((Math.PI * 2) / this.settings.seconds) * secondsElapsed);
        }
        this._clearRect();
        if (secondsElapsed < this.settings.seconds) {
            this._drawCountdownShape(Math.PI * 3.5, false);
            this._drawCountdownShape(endAngle, true);
            this._drawCountdownLabel(secondsElapsed);
        } else {
            this._drawCountdownShape(Math.PI * 3.5, this.settings.clockwise);
            this._drawCountdownLabel(this.settings.seconds);
            this.stop();
            this.settings.onComplete();
        }
    }
```

You simply add a `clockwise: true` when you create the countdown:

```
var countdown = $("#countdown").countdown360({
    radius: 60,
    seconds: 20,
    label: ['sec', 'secs'],
    fontColor: '#FFFFFF',
    autostart: false,
    clockwise: true,     // <<<<< Added this
    onComplete: function () {
        console.log('done');
    }
});
```